# JavaScript: can an input type=checkbox use appendChild in IE8 or not?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-8, input, appendchild

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535934(v=VS.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535262(v=VS.85).aspx , I should be able to do the following to create a new checkbox:

```
var answer = document.createElement('input');
answer.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
answer.setAttribute('id',   'answer');
answer.setAttribute('value', 'a');
answer.appendChild(document.createTextNode('test'));
```

This works in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE 8, the last function call produces the following error message:

```
Error: Unexpected call to method or property access.
```

I have tried bypassing this by using the **innerText** attribute instead, but this approach receives the same error message.

Am I doing something wrong?  If so, what?  If not, how can I circumvent what appears to be nonsense?

Comment: > *This works in Firefox and Chrome* O RLY?

Comment: Ah.  A little more digging showed that I read the HTML form examples a bit too quickly. The text for the inputs is not actually enclosed by the input tags.  At least Firefox and Chrome didn't report errors on the function call...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want to add a text node to your checkbox. Instead I would use a label object with two child nodes: the checkbox input and a text node:

```
var answer = document.createElement('input');
answer.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
answer.setAttribute('id',   'answer');
answer.setAttribute('value', 'a');
var answerLabel = document.createElement('label');
answerLabel.setAttribute('for','answer'); // this corresponds to the checkbox id
answerLabel.appendChild(answer);
answerLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' test'));
document.body.appendChild(answerLabel);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var label = document.createElement('label');
label.answer;
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('test'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It mostly worked, but I had to change the middle line to "label.setAttribute('for', 'answer');" to get it done all the way.

Comment: Strange... It should work without `for`. For example, look [this](http://htmlbook.ru/html/label)